# Edit Data in Django Unable to show the data

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Django to build a website. Modal bootstrap is what I'm utilizing. All works good for add, and delete data. However, In the Django form, I am unable to appear the data stored in the database for the update. Appreciate your help maybe I did something wrong with my code. I am not sure if my html or modal is correct. Thank you

-->> HTML <<--

```
                                <!-- Table Header  -->
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>User ID</th>
                                        <th>Username</th>
                                        <th>First Name</th>
                                        <th>Middle Name</th>
                                        <th>Last Name</th>
                                        <th>Role</th>
                                        <th>Created Date</th>
                                        <th>Modified Date</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Settings</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <!-- Table Body  -->
                                <tbody>
                                    {% for members in member %}
            
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{members.id}}</td>
                                        <td>{{members.username}}</td>
                                        <td>{{members.first_name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{members.middle_name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{members.last_name}}</td>
                                        <td>{% if members.role %}{{members.get_role}}{% endif %}</td>
                                        <td>{{members.created_date}}</td>
                                        <td>{{members.modified_date}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            {% if members.status == 1 %}
                                            <button type="button"
                                                class="btn btn-success rounded-pill">{{members.get_status}}</button>
                                            {% elif members.status == 2 %}
                                            <button type="button"
                                                class="btn btn-danger rounded-pill">{{members.get_status}}</button>
                                            {% elif members.status == 3 %}
                                            <button type="button"
                                                class="btn btn-secondary rounded-pill">{{members.get_status}}</button>
                                            {% endif %}

                                           
                                          
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewUserModal{{ members.id }}"><i class='bx bxs-folder-open'
                                                data-toggle="tooltip" title="View"></i></a>
                                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUserModal{{ members.id }}"><i class='bx bxs-edit'
                                                    data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"></i></a>
                                            
                                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal{{ members.id }}"><i class='bx bx-trash'
                                                    data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" ></i></a>
                                                    
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    {% include 'includes/modals.html' %}  
                            
                                   {% endfor %}
                                </tbody>
                                <!-- End of Table Body  -->

                            </table>
                        </div>
```

-->> Edit Modal <<--

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="editUserModal{{ members.id }}" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit User Account</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>First Name</label>
                {{form.first_name}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Middle Name</label>
                {{form.middle_name}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                {{form.last_name}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                {{form.email}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mobile Number</label>
                {{form.mobile_number}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username</label>
                {{form.username}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Role</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="inputGroupSelect01" name="role" value="{% if members.role %}{{members.get_role}}{% endif %}" required>
                    <option>Select Role</option>
                    <option value="2" {% if members.role == 1 %}{{members.get_role}} selected {% endif %} >Member</option>
                    <option value="2" {% if members.role == 2 %}{{members.get_role}} selected {% endif %} >Admin</option>
                    <option value="3" {% if members.role == 3 %}{{members.get_role}} selected {% endif %}>Super Admin</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Status</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="inputGroupSelect01" name="role" value="{% if members.status %}{{members.get_status}}{% endif %}" required>
                    <option>Select Status</option>
                    <option value="1" {% if members.status == 1 %}{{members.get_status}} selected {% endif %} >Active</option>
                    <option value="2" {% if members.status == 2 %}{{members.get_status}} selected {% endif %}>Deactive</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'edit_user' members.id %}" value="Save">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

-->> urls.py <<--

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('userAccounts/edit_user/<user_id>', views.edit_user, name='edit_user'),

]
```

-->> forms.py <<--

```
class UserFormAdmin(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'mobile_number', 'password']
    labels = {
        'first_name': '',
        'middle_name': '',
        'last_name': '',
        'mobile_number': '',
        'email': '',
        'username': '',
        'password': '',
        'confirm_password': '',
    }

first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Jones', 'class': 'form-control', }))
middle_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'A', 'class': 'form-control', }))
last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Smith', 'class': 'form-control',}))
mobile_number = forms.CharField(max_length=15, validators=[RegexValidator(
    '^\+[0-9]{1,3}\.?\s?\d{8,13}', message="Phone number must not consist of space and requires country code. eg : +639171234567")],widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '09123456789', 'class': 'form-control',}),
                                error_messages={'unique': ("Mobile Number already exists.")})

email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'jonesmith@gmail.com', 'class': 'form-control',}),
                        error_messages={'unique': ("Email already exists.")},)
username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Jones_Smith31', 'class': 'form-control',}),
                           error_messages={'unique': ("Username already exists.")},)
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': '********', 'class': 'form-control',}))
#password = forms.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(8),RegexValidator('^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])$', message="Password should be a combination of Alphabets and Numbers")], widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': '********', 'style': 'width: 460px; '}))
confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': '********', 'class': 'form-control', }))
```

-->> views.py <<--

```
def sa_userAccount_admin(request):
member = User.objects.filter(role = 2)
form = UserFormAdmin(request.POST)
context = {
    'form': form,
    'member': member,
}
print(context)
return render(request, 'pages/sa_userAccount.html', context)

def edit_user(request, user_id):
member = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
form = UserFormAdmin(request.POST or None, instance=member)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect('sa_userAccount')
return render(request, 'pages/sa_userAccount.html', 
    {'members': member,
    'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following steps:

1. get user input to update an object in HTML Modal
2. send data using the POST method with object `pk`
3. fetch object using received `pk`
4. update object in views using `setattr(object,field name,value)` from POST data
5. call `object.save()` method

These steps will update your objects in the database using the partial update technique.